# Ionic - run performance tests directly on device

Tags: android, performance, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic 1 app designed to run on a specific android device.

I cannot find a way to easily get performance metrics (memory usage, cpu, fps, etc.) from that device ?

All performance tools I found (browser-perf, PerfJankie, etc.) seem to require emulators, which I don't use. I test the app in my browser (with `ionic serve`) and then directly on the device (with `ionic cordova run android --device`). It's important for me to have the performance stats from that specific device.

Thanks !